# running multiple windows of powershell with different commands in one script

Tags: powershell

I am pretty new to this and I am trying to learn how to write a script that allows me to open multiple powershell windows and have each one run its own command. I haven't been able to figure out the answer to this question anywhere. I am open to suggestions and happy to learn from you guys. Cheers

Comment: Why is it important that the commands run in separate windows? Which commands do you need to run?

Comment: I'm trying to run sg_format and basically BPS change for at least 24 SAS Drives at once and it won't allow me to run them parallel unless they are in separate windows. I have a script that opens 50 PS windows at once but it won't allow me to run the next command for each window